# Partitioning a table in databricks

Tags: databricks

Can someone enlighten whether I can partition a table on a column and restrict access only to certain partitions to certain people?

What and how does table partition has anything to do with restricting access ? for example: if I have a partition by Country, with around 150+ countries can we restrict access only to 10 states at partition level?

Thanks

Comment: how would you assign permissions per partitions? Do you have some table that maps users or groups into partitions?

Comment: Try creating a view with specific states and grant access to that view.

Comment: You can try and create dynamic views and groups in databricks with each group having access to certain data can refer to below link for sample query [link](https://github.com/databricks-academy/advanced-data-engineering-with-databricks/blob/4fcda73737f3b15f8ab4511253ff32394b494040/Advanced-Data-Engineering-with-Databricks/03%20-%20Privacy%20and%20Governance%20for%20Lakehouse%20Analytics/ADE%203.05%20-%20Deidentified%20PII%20Access.py)